# How to output a query with dynamic columns in PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql, pivot

In my PostgreSQL database I have an invitations table like so:

**Invitations Table:**

```
CREATE TABLE invitations
( id           INTEGER
, created_at   TIMESTAMP
, source       TEXT
, completed_at TIMESTAMP
);
```

**Desired Results:**

```
COLUMNS: date_start | date_end | total_invites | % by unique source....
```

Where the columns`% by unique source` is dynamic based on how many unique sources are found in the field Invitations.source

Is it possible to make the columns dynamic based on the unique items in the `Invitations.source` field? How?

Comment: What would the value be for the `invitations.source` field after it is made into a column?

Comment: @JSpratt the value would be the % of the records completed by that source.

Comment: Can you please **[edit]** your question (by clicking on the [edit] link below it) and add some sample data and the expected output based on that data as [formatted text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362). See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81852) for some tips on how to create nice looking text tables.

Answer (score 3):

I believe you are looking for some window function and CTE (common table expression) use here.

```
WITH dataset AS                                               -- CTE
(
    SELECT created_at      AS date_start
         , completed_at    AS date_end
         , source
         , COUNT(*) OVER() AS total_invites                   -- window function
         , COUNT(*) OVER(PARTITION BY source) AS source_count -- window function
      FROM invitations
)
SELECT date_start
     , date_end
     -- , source
     , total_invites
     -- , source_count
     , (source_count::double precision / total_invites::double precision) * 100 AS source_perc
  FROM dataset
;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=f4969d14f2d3b0c9ce2eb23c49edfe41) is a db<>fiddle with a demonstration of the query supplied in this answer for you to take a look at.

It was a little unclear whether you were looking for a cumulative percentage or a total percentage. I've supplied the total percentage but cumulative is possible as well.

Comment: your link to the dbfiddle has an incorrect URL (just FYI)

Comment: Thank you, that has been fixed.

Comment: @JSpratt thank you for taking the time to help. I just tried the query. While I get results, there are a few problems. The sources are not being grouped by uniqueness. for example, if a source is "A" I'm getting multiple rows for "A" -- the idea is to group by unique source, and see per source what is the completion rate per source in one row.

Comment: You're getting multiple rows because of the timestamps. Are you looking to view the rate in a certain time range? For example, what is the completion rate per source from 2020-03-31 to 2020-04-01? I have updated the fiddle with multiple other options.